# Can I reuse test data as training data?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using cnn to classify images. I have 1000 images to begin my journey. So I use 900 as training dataset and 100 as testing dataset. I got a model of ~70% correctness.

Then I get another 150 images today. so I have two ideas to continue:

(1) Can I combine the previous 100 test data + 900 train data to be a "new" training set so I can have 1000 training data to get a possibly better model? Then I can use the new 150 images as the new "test" data?

(2) Can I combine the new 150 images + 900 train data to be a "new" training set to train a better model and still continue to use the previous 100 test data set to test the new model?

Obviously I am going to try both but I am not sure in theory which one is better... Any comments? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should train on as much data as possible if you want the best CNN possible. Theory says that the more training data you have, the closer your test error will be to your training error. That means your CNN will be better at classifying examples it wasn't trained on. On the other hand, you don't want too little test data because you need to be confident in your accuracy measurement. So you should ideally get more training and more testing data.

If your data is **IID**, then you shouldn't worry about which of the 1150 images are used to train your model.

The only danger of reusing the same test data is that you might change the model (e.g., adding another layer, and/or adding more units to an existing layer) because it gives you a better result on your test data. When you alter your model in response to observations of the test error, you risk overfitting to your data. You can mitigate this problem by using a third data set, known as a validation set, for tweaking your model.

**IID**: The total 1150 images are independently drawn from an identical distribution. In other words, roughly speaking, there's nothing differentiating the 150 from the 1000 aside from the fact that they're new to you, and each image's selection wasn't affected by the selection of any other image.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter as long as the new 150 images are from the same distribution as that of the previous 1000 samples.

Comment: I was not sure if I could use the same test data set again and again.. So it may be fine if I continue to use the same 100 test data and keep adding new data into training set? Yes they are from same distribution.

Comment: As long as your model is not looking at test data for fitting the model parameters it is fine. Prediction using the model does not effect learned parameters of the model, so you can use the same test data again and again. In ML a decent train-test split is normally 75-25 or 80-20. If you think you have too less data for split try k fold cross validation.